# Overlay effect without position:fixed;

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to have a background-image with some overlay effect.

see: https://jsbin.com/giqagidufe/edit?html,css,output

The overlay effect should always be full screen size - also when resizing. I first did that using:

```
html, body { min-height: 100%; }

// Background Image
body {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Header/header_full.jpg");
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: black !important;
}

// Colored overlay of Background Image
body::before {
    position:absolute;
    content: '';
    background-color: rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.7);
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -10; 
}
```

so I used `position:absolute;` but that has the problem of not fully cover the whole screen. I thend used `position:fixed;` which solves the problem.

but that forces the browser to rerender the whole thing on each scroll, so it's not the best option.

Are there any other option I could do that? One which is more performant?

Comment: In what way is the JSBin example not working? The overlay seems to cover the whole page. Bit unclear what you are having trouble with at the moment.

Comment: Right now your background-image won't continue covering the screen if you need to scroll, so if your page is going to extend past the initial browser viewport, you'll need to change it to `background-attachment: fixed;`. (To see this happen, make a 2000px high `<div>` in the `body` and notice the bg stays on top.) I don't think there's anything wrong with fixing this blue overlay if you need it - but the question is, why isn't it just baked into the background JPG?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "*but that forces the browser to rerender the whole thing on each scroll, so it's not the best option*". Using `position:fixed` is the common approach to full size overlays. Please explain a bit more what you want to happen when you scroll etc.

Comment: It isn't backed into the background-image because that might change and the site will be maintained by people who have no clue - this way they can just upload a pic with proper size. the first answer solved it. The problem was, that it didn't fully cover the screen - at least for me. position:fixed forces to rerender the fixed part on each "scroll event". Like if you scroll just a little bit - it get's rerendered. At least afaik. So having a fixed element spanning over the whole page, the performance might suck. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we're on the same page, this is what you're looking for.
Please let me know if this solves your problem.

You should place both elements (image and overlay) as absolute.
You can play with the last param of the RGBA property of class overlay to set the opacity.

It's fully responsive, which adheres to your question.
Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyojwq77/1/)

**HTML**

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { min-height: 100%; }
body {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    background-image: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/8fWGVfB.jpg");
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.overlay{
    width:100%; 
    min-height:100%; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: hi, so this is another approach which I also thought about. Rethinking it, it probably is better since it uses less fancy methods. Anyway, theres an error in your example: you should use min-height:100; in .overlay{} otherwise it won't work properly. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is adding `background-attachment: fixed` to your `body` tag. This will keep the background fixed no matter what height the `body` has.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(http://hdwallpaper20.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/4k-wallpaper-15-ULTRA-HD-Collections-Yosemite-Valley-Snow-Sunset-4K-Ultra-HD-Desktop-Wallpaper-1024x576.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Can be a div with some content</div>
</body>
```

Comment: hi, seems to not work as expected - I want to get ride of position:fixed;

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your body:

```
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Comment: thanks, didn't try since the first answer seemed to work just as I wanted it to work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add this to the pool if someone is looking for the same thing as me. Haven't tested this thouroghly and I am unsure about support but it is CSS Grid that has been here for a while now.

I wanted the whole page covered without the overlay and its content being fixed and without having to use overflow-y: scroll. I also wanted the page scroll to work as usual to show the entire page even if it is overlayed. The solution i found was to use CSS Grid on the body to make a one column one row grid and then place your page and overlay in the same cell in that grid. CSS Grid then overlaps the cells and also seem to respect z-index.

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

#page {
    grid-column: 1 /2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.overlay {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.overlay-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="page">Here is some example text on my page</div>
<div class="overlay"><div class="overlay-content">My overlay content</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```